# Bash scripts are not working but on mac terminal those commands in scripts works

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I'm stuck with a wired problem.My bash scripts are not working now.It worked previously.I don't know why.Interestingly the commands on the script work when I enter it directly on the terminal.

This a sample line from  my script `ls`

On the terminal when I run `sh  ./check.sh`, the output is `: command not found ls`

The output is similar for other commands also,except `echo` for which is showing the correct output.

I request every kind people to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the script with a DOS (windows) editor, that's added a \r (carriage return) to the end of every line.

You can convert the file with:

```
dos2unix check.sh check.sh.tmp && mv check.sh.tmp check.sh
```

I personally usually do `vim check.sh` and then `:set notx` and then save the file: `:wq`

Comment: I don't have dos2unix installed Ic choose the second `vim` method.Thank You So much..